# SQL Server install on 64 bit Windows 7 installing as 32 bit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, 64-bit

I am attempting to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on a new 64 bint Windows workstation.
I wish to install the 64 bit version and am using this iso file:

```
en_sql_server_2008_r2_developer_x86_x64_ia64_dvd_522665.iso
```

But it has repeatedly started installing the the 32 bit (x86) version. 
I cannot figure out how to get the installation process to install the 64 bit version.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

When I've run into that it's been because the installer detected previously installed 32-bit SQL components.  In my case I was able to just blow out the 32-bit components and reinstall the 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

What is leading you to believe that it is installing 32 bit? Is it because you see SQL installed into the c:\PF\SQL(x86) folder?

You can run `select @@version` and find out what SQL actually installed as.